# Flutter Could not prepare to run the isolate

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator, dart, flutter

I started a flutter project using Android studio. The android emulator opened the project smoothly. When I opened the Ios emulator, the project worked smoothly. When I ran the android emulator again, project isn't runed . Thanks for your help.

**Android Studio Features :**

- Android Studio 3.0
- Build #AI-171.4408382, built on October 20, 2017
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08 x86_64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Mac OS X 10.12.6

**Flutter :** v0.4.4 Beta

**Console :**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
I/FlutterActivityDelegate( 2747): onResume setting current activity to this
E/flutter ( 2747): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(147)] Could not prepare to run the isolate.
E/flutter ( 2747): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(112)] Engine not prepare and launch isolate.
E/flutter ( 2747): [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/android_shell_holder.cc(138)] Could not launch engine in configuration.
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Application finished.
```

Comment: Share some of your code.

Comment: @Bostrot There is default project. Counter project.

Comment: Did you run `flutter doctor`?

Comment: You would get this error when something is messed up with the `main()` method in the `main.dart` file.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you are facing the problem even if you have main method in main.dart inside your lib folder

Try

```
flutter clean
```

And then

```
flutter run
```

Worked for me :)

Answer (score 52):

I had the same error and it happened when I didn't write the main method.
so do this

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

> MyApp is my main class

Comment: Ha! Some reason the refactoring in VSCode deleted this method, got me confused for a full several minutes. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 17):

if you use VS code editor, make sure you **press the run button only when the main.dart file is opened**. Pressing run when other files are opened also causes this error.

**Another file is opened**, pressing run will cause the error:
[image: Another file is opened, running program now will cause the error]

**Main.dart file is opened**, now you can run your program:
[image]

Comment: This helped me, but why? Can I fix this in some way, like specify where is the main file so that I don't need to go to it every time I want to start the app?

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76270978/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @PrzemysławWrzesiński Main.dart is the start for any flutter app, so you only need to run your app from that file. I think full-blown IDEs have that feature by default like android studio or Visual Studio IDE but I couldn't find the same for VS code editor

Comment: Thanks @Atul ! I found a way to do it - you need to create a `launch.json` file as described [here](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-run-flutter-app-with-arguments-in-vscode-with-launch-configuration/) which you can use to configure the app and then add the `"program"` argument to all configurations, see [here](https://dartcode.org/docs/launch-configuration/)

Answer (score 4):

1. please check whether your Flutter Project contains`main.dart` in `lib` folder, if not, create it.
2. check your code like this:

```java
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:module_flutter/xxxApp.dart';

void main() => runApp( new xxxApp());
```

Answer (score 4):

make sure that you are clicked debug on the main.dart page and you won't face this error again,
in case try to debug from another page you will face this error.

Answer (score 3):

1. Check device or emulator has enough storage, if not uninstall some for making space
2. remove the cache folder `rm -rf ${FLUTTER_ROOT}/bin/cache`
3. `flutter clean`
4. `flutter run`

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar situation and the main reason was that my application runs using multiple flavors and in the tag '**program**' of the flavors configuration (in the case of VS code), I found a different entry point file (ex: app.dart) and the correct entry point was other (main.dart)

```
{
            "name": "xyz",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main.dart", //here was the problem
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "dev"
            ]
        }
```

Hope this can help someone!

Answer (score 2):

Below commands on the terminal worked for me.

1. Flutter pub cache clean
2. Flutter pub get
3. Flutter clean
4. Flutter packages get

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me when used "Start Debugging" button in VS code that at the top and right of window while opening another `dart` file (Not `main.dart`).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error. I tried many ways and this is the right way.

You need to run

```
flutter build ios --debug (or --profile or --release)
```

before you launch the project in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

These methods will maybe work restart android studio, run flutter clean, reinstall flutter in the same location:- be careful when doing, check the SDK is installed and if installed the check the SDK is in the project or not, check the project code again and again. click get dependencies to get everything in the project, check spelling mistakes. I Hope Your Project runs Smooth Now.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your main function is using run-app.

```
void main() {
  runApp(PageName());
}
```

This mentioned above should be present.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen due to two reasons mainly:

1. You do not have a main() function set up properly.
2. You try to run it from other folders other than main.dart.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me. Eventually I uninstalled the previously installed one (but failed to run for another reason). Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my .vscode folder and that solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you'r app is not running **multiple instances**. Try to stop them all first.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. Just go you your main.dart file and verify if it has

```
void main(){
runApp(MyApp());
}
```

before 'class MyApp extends StatelessWidget'

Now save the file by "CTRL+S" and run you app. It will solve your problem. Hope you find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

I am using visual studio code, I had same error. I run command,

1. Flutter clean
2. Flutter packages get

Make sure your main method is correct.

Also, Visual studio code needs "main.dart" file to be opened while you run the debug command.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this will occur if you have not written the `void main(){ runApp(const MyApp())}` so make sure you have done that

Comment: This was already explained in the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51327262), please upvote that instead of posting a new answer or explain whether and how your answer is different.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**There might unique condition like mine.**

If your project have environment setup(like mine is `DEV` and `PROD`).

And if you want to run project in `DEV` mode then you should run project from `dev_main.dart` and similarly for `PROD`.