# Error -32000 received from application: Could not run configuration in engine. #Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

> Performing hot restart..
>
> Syncing files to device Redmi Note
>   5...
>
> E/flutter (23513): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(178)] Dart Error: Can't load
>   Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
>
> E/flutter
>   (23513): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(188)] Could not prepare
>   to run the isolate.
>
> E/flutter (23513):
>   [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(127)] Engine not prepare and
>   launch isolate.
>
> Error -32000 received from application: Could
>   not run configuration in engine.
>
> Restarted application in 2,185ms.

When i build for the 1st time it's working fine but after i try to hot restart or build then this error occur.
what are the reasons??
TIA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654820/flutter-could-not-prepare-to-run-the-isolate

Comment: The issue solved thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you will encounter this issue if there is no main method present in your code. Your code should have this line for example:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

But iff you are still facing the issue even if you have main method in main.dart inside your lib folder:

Try

```
flutter clean
```

And then

```
flutter run
```