# Flutter complains that it "Could not prepare isolate"

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The error looks like this:

```
E/flutter ( 3378): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(144)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter ( 3378): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(422)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter ( 3378): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(609)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

I am getting this error when I use `StatefulWidget` and `StatelessWidgets`. I don't get these errors when I write code without using them.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

I had this error before because I forgot to use the runApp(MyApp()) in void main

Answer (score 0):

The Stackoverflow Thread on ["Flutter Could not prepare to run the isolate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654820/flutter-could-not-prepare-to-run-the-isolate) might be helpful.

If you are facing the problem that even if you have the main method in `main.dart` inside your `lib` folder, then you could try the following.

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Answer (score -1):

try flutter clean.

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get
```

Comment: I tried this way. Unfortunately, the result did not change

Comment: It would be helpful for the questioner if you would elaborate why this solution should work.

Comment: Please consider checking your main.dart file then.